# Can a local variable with an inferred type be reassigned to a different type?

Tags: java, object, variables, type-inference, java-10

I remember reading somewhere that local variables with inferred types can be reassigned with values of the same type, which would make sense.

```
var x = 5;
x = 1; // Should compile, no?
```

However, I'm curious what would happen if you were to reassign `x` to an object of a different type.  Would something like this still compile?

```
var x = 5;
x = new Scanner(System.in); // What happens?
```

I'm currently not able to install an early release of JDK 10, and did not want to wait until tomorrow to find out.

Comment: if they are both the same types then it should work otherwise no. speaking from experience in C# and I believe the use of `var` in java functions the same way.

Comment: Type inference is not dynamic typing.  It's simply the compiler figuring out the type of a variable from the type of its initializer.  Once the compiler infers `int` for `x` in your declaration, you have declared a variable of type `int`.  That's the whole story; inference plays no additional part.

Comment: Btw *not able to install an early release of JDK 10* (for what reasons? what failures or errors) could've been a better question asked. ;)

Comment: @nullpointer Entirely unrelated :P it's a school-issued computer and they don't want us installing things, unfortunately!

Comment: :) Maybe you're right. But then look at this perspective, your question might simply sound like *"I am not able to install Java, can someone let me know if `int x = 1;` compiles while working with it?"* Isn't it? And then the answers are like, *I've tried it on so and so machine. Yes, it compiles* or *No, it doesn't.*

Comment: Of course not, why would you think that? `Scanner` and `int` are two completely different unrelated types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would not compile, throws *"incompatible types: Scanner cannot be converted to int"*. Local variable type inference does not change the static-typed nature of Java. In other words:

```
var x = 5;
x = new Scanner(System.in);
```

is just syntactic sugar for:

```
int x = 5;
x = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: That's what I thought.  Just curious, but what error does the compiler throw?

Comment: @JacobG. Tried it on the EA OpenJDK --> "incompatible types: Scanner cannot be converted to int"

Comment: Makes sense, so it *is* just syntactic sugar.  Thank you!

Comment: @manouti there is a follow sort of question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410939/useful-applications-of-intersection-types-using-local-type-inference while this is indeed syntactic sugar, the *type* of var can be inferred by the compiler, and there are types the compiler can infer that we can not declare

Comment: @Eugene Interesting post. You're right in this particular case it's syntactic sugar. With non-denotable types, it's more of an implicit typing of something that we couldn't express before.

Answer (score 4):

Once a `var` variable has been initialized, you cannot reassign it to a different type as the type has already been inferred.

so, for example this:

```
var x = 5;
x = 1;
```

would compile as `x` is inferred to be `int` and reassigning the value `1` to it is also fine as they're the same type.

on the other hand, something like:

```
var x = 5;
x = "1";
```

will not compile as `x` is inferred to be `int` hence assigning a `string` to `x` would cause a compilation error.

the same applies to the `Scanner` example you've shown, it will fail to compile.