# Does using var with a literal result in a primitive or a primitive wrapper class?

Tags: java, type-inference, local-variables, java-10

After reading and talking about Java 10s new reserved type name **`var`**
([JEP 286: Local-Variable Type Inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)), one question arose in the discussion.

When using it with literals like:

```
var number = 42;
```

is `number` now an `int` or an `Integer`? If you just use it with comparison operators or as a parameter it usually doesn't matter thanks to autoboxing and -unboxing.
But due to `Integer`s member functions it *could matter*.

So which type is created by `var`, a primitive `int` or class `Integer`?

Comment: Nevertheless, one way was to surely try it out, where you could have tried to see that `number instanceof Integer` wouldn't work for your case(as `instanceof` wouldn't work for primitive types). While if the number, on the other hand, would have been casted to `(Integer) 42`. [It would have worked.](https://tio.run/##ZU29DsIgGJzLU9xIBxudGx/AwamjcfikSKiUNvCV1Jg@OzLoordccr8DJdoN/SPnebk5q6AcxYgzWY@XqD5iZOJCabI9xmLJjoP15nIFBRPrksQPEgWsOEKePGujQ43Dvv1Ldc/IemymhZu5DLLzcoX15c4rPd3xLbei2sSW8xs)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`var` asks the compiler to infer the type of the variable from the type of the initializer, and the natural type of `42` is `int`.  So `number` will be an `int`. That is what the [JLS example says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4.1):

```
var a = 1;  // a has type 'int'
```

And I would be surprised if it worked any other way, when I write something like this, I definitely expect a primitive.

If you need a `var` as boxed primitive, you could do:

```
var x = (Integer) 10;  // x is now an Integer
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so goes my thinking, too but do you have  a reference for it?

Comment: The only "benefit" of having a generic `var` type IMO is the ability to assign dynamic properties to it, C# and JS-like. Like `var a = {}; a.arbitraryProperty = "hey!";` - however, it doesn't seem to be possible (I might be wrong though).

Comment: @BackSlash you can sort of do it `var x = new Object() {
            int y;
            int z;
        };

        int test = x.y;` And that is possible only with types that are inferred by the compiler, see also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410939/useful-applications-of-intersection-types-using-local-type-inference

Comment: @BackSlash I just [read about this](https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference), it is mostly to reduce the verbosity. I begin to understand where this could be useful, this was restricted to local variable so it would not be a mess like JS (and other language too I think).

Comment: @BackSlash: What you are talking about is *dynamic typing*. What this question is about, is *implicit typing*. Those are two completely different things.

Comment: @Eugene You are using the term "syntactic sugar" incorrectly.  This is not a purely syntactic transform.

Comment: @BrianGoetz thank you for the edit, and yes, it makes a lot of sense that it is more than synthetic sugar...

Comment: Well, `var x = (Integer) 10;` takes more keystokes than `Integer x = 10;` so I'll stay with the latter probably.

Answer (score 13):

According to the [proposed specification changes](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151553) in 14.4.1 *Local Variable Declarators and Types*:

> If *LocalVariableType* is `var`, then let *T* be the type of the initializer expression when treated as if it did not appear in an assignment context, and were thus a standalone expression ([15.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2)). The type of the local variable is the upward projection of *T* with respect to all synthetic type variables mentioned by *T* (4.10.5).

In other words, the inferred type for the local variable is the type that the initializer expression would have if it were used as a standalone expression. `42` as a standalone expression has type `int`, ergo, the variable `number` is of type `int`.

*Upward projection* is a term defined in the spec changes that doesn't apply to simple cases like this.

Comment: I'm not sure it needs to go into the answer itself, but I was curious what _upward projection_ actually is, since this answer only tells you one thing it is not.  A one sentence summary in the linked specification changes for upward projection: "The type of the initializer is mapped to a supertype using 'upward projection', eliminating any capture variables or anonymous classes."

Answer (score 8):

Let's test it. With jshell:

```
jshell> Integer boxed1 = 42000;
boxed1 ==> 42000

jshell> Integer boxed2 = 42000;
boxed2 ==> 42000

jshell> System.out.println(boxed1 == boxed2);
false

jshell> var infered1 = 42000;
infered1 ==> 42000

jshell> var infered2 = 42000;
infered2 ==> 42000

jshell> System.out.println(infered1 == infered2);
true
```

In the first comparison, the two variables are not the same; they're different instances. The second comparison is however true, hence an int must've been infered here.

Note: To try it at home, use values outside <-128, 128). Integer instances in that range are cached.

Comment: This is a very roundabout proof. And you're relying on implementation details of the Integer cache... A better proof would be simply `var i = 10` followed by `i instanceof Integer`. You'll get `ERROR: unexpected type` because it's an int and not a reference.

Comment: And just FYI, you don't need `System.out.println`. Just evaluate `infered1 == infered2` on it's own.

Comment: Michael, yeh, I thought of instanceof for a second, but didn't try. I should have :)

Comment: In general, I like the "proof" by code but for a more general answer, JLS is still better. An implementation can be changed, unless this is written in the JLS. But since i never though about when to use `Jshell`, I like this answer !

Comment: @AxelH Agree. If an answer is based on empiricism, I'd say you should always state what version you're testing with.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler treats `var number = 42;` similarly to `int number = 42;`

```
public void method(Integer i) {
    System.out.print("Integer method");
}
public void method(int i) {
    System.out.print("int method");
}

var n = 42; // n has type 'int' 
method(n); // => "int method"
```

And auto-boxing when:

```
public void method(Integer i) {
    System.out.print("Integer method");
}

var n = 42; // a has type 'int'
method(n); // => "Integer method"
```